# Why Mission Control is causing NSScrollView borders to show up?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My app has three `NSTableView` and two `NSTextView`, I have chosen not to draw border of `NSScrollView` which is `superView` of each one of above. This works fine but when I activate Mission Control, the borders become visible.

ScreenShot:

[![NSScrollView Properties][2]][2]

[2[image: ]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehi7a.png

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error, the solution was to uncheck textured window in NSWindow property. This solved the problem.